# Should I ask about promotion opportunites after receiving a job offer?

Tags: job-offer

Here is my situation. I am a government employee working in the Finance and Accounting career field. I've been working for the same agency for the past 10+ years and decided that I needed a change. I went job hunting and landed a job in another agency. It was a long process. I applied in January, got interviewed in May, and received the job offer at the end of August. While that was happening, my organisation went through a reorg in May and I ended up being reassigned to another department/team. I also received a temporary promotion in July with a possibility of making it a permanent promotion in the next couple of months. I don't know what to do now. I thought about contacting the agency who gave me the job offer to ask them if there are any promotion opportunities in the future. However, I'm not sure if that would be appropriate.

Do I ask the agency?

Answer (score 9):

You should contact them, this is definite grounds for renegotiation or refusing the job offer altogether. Circumstances change over time, you are under no obligations yet.

It's a bad idea to go backwards in a career without an overriding reason that I don't see here. Finance and accounting jobs in my experience have promotions few and far between even in the private sector.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of uncertainty here as you aren't guaranteed the permanent promotion in your current job, but at the same time your job that's lined up does not have guaranteed promotion either.

The best thing to do here is ask the new agency whether there would be any opportunities for promotions as you have received a better offer. Or disguise it a little bit by saying

> Hi, would there be any chances for progression upon starting this role?

Obviously the employers know's what you mean but it's a little more indirect.
However asking the employer whether or not there would be promotions is potentially pointless as they can easily say yes then just reject anything in the future. Even if you get this in writing it isn't exactly part of the contract or a guarantee either.

The safest option here would be to stick at your current job and see if you get the promotion or not. Potentially even delay your start date at the new agency (if possible)